# foreach loop in Zend Framework 1 wont return multiple results in json output

Tags: php, arrays, json, zend-framework

I have built up a script to first query table 'linkags' in database for id's where 'id' is equal to 'userId' and 'type' is equal to 'type'.

I then use the result to query table 'linktagRevisions' to fetch the latest revision for the returned array of id's pertaining to that user.

I then output the list of 'linktagRevisions' in to a json output.

My issue has been that I have been unable to unserialize 'content'. So in building my array to output in json I have coded:

$data = array('linktag' => unserialize($result[$linkI]['content']));

Which successfully returns an unserialzed result, but it limits to one row even with the foreach loop in place. How can I use the loop to fetch all rows?

Here is my full code:

```
public function testAction()

{
    //Return list of tags for the defined user and make default type 10
    $u = 2;
    $t = 10;

    $resultid = array();

    //Connect to database
    $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
    $select = $db->select()
        ->from(array('lt' => 'Linktags'),
            array('id'))
        ->where('userId = ?', $u)
        ->where('type = ?', $t);

    $stmt = $select->query();
    $resultid = $stmt->fetchAll();


   //print_r($resultid);

    //Get latest revision from database and loop through $id's

    $id = $resultid;

    //print_r($id);

    //setup array and loop

    $result = array();

    foreach($id as $lId_all) {
        foreach($lId_all as $lId) {

            //Connect to database

            $db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();

            //Perform Query
            $select = $db->select('')
                ->from(array('lr' => 'LinktagRevisions'),
                    array('content'))
                ->where('linktagId = ?', $lId)
                ->order('updated DESC')
                ->limit(1);


            $stmt = $select->query();
            $result[$lId] = $stmt->fetch();


        }

    }

    $linkId = $resultid;

    foreach ($linkId as $linkI_all) {
        foreach ($linkI_all as $linkI) {

            //print_r($linkI);

            $data = array('linktag' => unserialize($result[$linkI]['content']));


        }
        print_r($data);


        $this->_helper->json($data, true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add link index like this:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($linkId as $linkI_all) {
    foreach ($linkI_all as $linkI) {
        $data['linktag'.$linkI] = unserialize($result[$linkI]['content']);
    }
}
$this->_helper->json($data, true);
```

Comment: Hi again doydoy44, you certainly know your stuff, I'm very grateful! I also got it working by adding $data[] = unserialize($result[$lId]['content']); on to the end of the query and changing the array to data. I'm going to try working with both and see if I can get the end result I'm looking for, which is a well formatted JSON API response.

Comment: @Ripwinder Hi again also :). It is a pleasure to help you. good luck in your search :)